# Setting PHP SESSION var from within JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session

Is there a way to set a session variable from withing my JS function?

I have the following JS code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
        tid: '.$testID.',
        do:"'.$do.'"
    },
    success: function( html ) {
        $("#partBox").html( html ); 
        // add PHP here?            
    }
});
```

I would like to set the following var in the session, on SUCCESS:

```
$_SESSION['hgt'] = 'Math.ceil($("#partBox").height() / 2)';
```

I have no idea if this is even possible... Alternatively I could probably use cookies...

Answer (score 5):

You can't set any PHP variables in JavaScript. Once the Page has finished loading PHP has done its job and is out of the picture. If you want to set a session variable using JavaScript you can do it one of two ways:

1. Use Ajax to send the value to a PHP script to set the session variable
2. Store it in a cookie and on the next page load have PHP use the value of that cookie to create the session varibale

Comment: I need to capture this value into a session to use in cases where I have not received SUCCESS response. And how do I send it over again with AJAX? Do I put another ajax call withing SUCCESS section?

Comment: That would be exactly where it goes

Comment: Hmm, that sounds a bit more convoluted than I can handle. Can I set a cookie from withing SUCCESS area?

Comment: To be honest; it's a best practice to use `both cookies and session variables`. Some users don't allow cookies.