# How to get li tag value by javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I need to get li value onclick function in php ...and want to store that in php session..
 i used my code for this but this is not working....
 i need to know that how to get li value on click function in java script..
 i NEED to get li tag value of on click function and want to store in php session by js or jquery

```
<li class="atleta" value="100" >
            <a href="#"  >Vendor Registration</a>
</li>

$('.atleta').click(function(e) {


            var <?php  $_SESSION['VENDR']?>  = $(this));

});
```

Comment: Why on earth would you use a PHP session variable as the name of a javascript variable. That makes no sense at all ?

Comment: Oh, now I see, you didn't get the execution order of **serverside** language and **clientside** language

Comment: There is no way to set a PHP variable like that, as the PHP code executes on the server, long before it ever reaches the browser and the javascript executes. You have to use ajax and send the value back to the server, but you can't send a jQuery object back, and there is no reason what so ever to do so either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565055/setting-php-session-var-from-within-js

Comment: btw you can do it by ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this and its working..

```
<li id="atleta" value="18" onclick="vendorData();">
            <a href="#" >Vendor Registration</a>
</li>

<script>

function vendorData(){
    var h = document.getElementById('atleta').value;
    localStorage.setItem("vendor", h);
    var ven = localStorage.getItem("vendor");

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Don't mix server side and client side technologies**.Instead to php session i will recommend to use `localStorage` instead and store clicked `li` value in it as shown :-

```
$('.atleta').click(function(e) {
   localStorage.setItem('lival',$(this).val());
});
```

and in order to get data stored in `localStorage` use this :-

```
var livalue = localStorage.getItem('lival');
```

[Reference](http://htmldog.com/guides/javascript/advanced/localstorage/)

Or Instead of localStorage you can use sessionStorage also(their basic usage is same except for some difference [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookie))

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
$('.atleta').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault(); //if needed
        var <?php  $_SESSION['VENDR']?>  = $(this).children('a').text();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your variable in cookies, so you can set it via jQuery and get in php later